# Naive bayes classifier Cutoff

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, opennlp

I´m using the following code to train my classifier:

```
public static DoccatModel trainClassifier() throws IOException
{                   
    // read the training data
    final int iterations = 100;
    InputStreamFactory dataIn = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(new File("src/main/resources/trainingSets/classifierA.txt"));
    ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
    ObjectStream<DocumentSample> sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);

    // define the training parameters
    TrainingParameters params = new TrainingParameters();
    params.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, iterations+"");
    params.put(TrainingParameters.CUTOFF_PARAM, 3+"");
    params.put(AbstractTrainer.ALGORITHM_PARAM, NaiveBayesTrainer.NAIVE_BAYES_VALUE);

    // create a model from traning data
    DoccatModel model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("NL", sampleStream, params, new DoccatFactory());

    OutputStream modelOut = null;
    modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/models/model.bin"));
    model.serialize(modelOut);

    return model;
}
```

Could anyone explain what the following code does in the training progress:

```
params.put(TrainingParameters.CUTOFF_PARAM, 3+"");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30262184/3374996) for explanation of `cutoff`. The trailing `+""` is just used to convert integer 3 to string.

Comment: Thanks for the good link, and the `+""` I was aware of.